# GitLab CI: unir rama 'dev' a 'master' cuando los test pasan

Tags: gitlab-ci

En la empresa tenemos GitLab funcionando en una maquina virtual. Tenemos un proyecto que tiene configurado el archivo de CI/CD para correr los tests.

Para trabajar, lo hacemos en la rama **dev**, la rama **master** no se toca. La idea es que a master solamente se carguen los commits de las otras ramas, en este caso **dev**.

Estoy intentando modificar el archivo de CI/CD para que la tarea de realizar el **merge**, una vez que pasan los tests, se automatice. Tengo pensado para más adelante que, en vez de realizar la tarea cuando pasan los tests, realizarla cuando la cobertura del código sea mayor a un porcentaje mínimo.

Entonces, investigando, no estoy encontrando información de como hacer esto. Dejo el archivo para que vean como está configurado actualmente.

```
image: debian:latest

stages:
  - test

before_script:
  - apt-get update -y
  - apt-get install apt-transport-https -y
  - apt-get install -y gnupg2
  ##Se instala java
  - apt-get install default-jdk -y
  - java -version
  ##Se instala CURL
  - apt-get install curl -y
  ##se instala SBT
  - echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
  - curl -sL "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823" | apt-key add
  - apt-get update -y
  - apt-get install sbt -y
  - sbt sbtVersion

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - sbt test;
```

¿Cómo puedo agregar a ese script para que cuando los tests pasen, automáticamente se haga un **merge** en la rama **master**?

Comment: ya revisaste la documentacicon ofocial?  **Merge when pipeline succeeds** https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/merge_when_pipeline_succeeds.html

Comment: No lo había visto. Pruebo y te confirmo.